# Getting the local IP address for a socket/network interface

Tags: windows-phone-7, network-protocols

I am trying to write a VoIP client for Windows Phone, and I can't find any way to get the phone's local IP Address. I can get its public IP (through STUN or visiting http://www.whatismyip.org/ or similar sites), but all connection attempts fail if both parties are on the same local network. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: looking through the windows phone 7 api, it seems microsoft doesn't allow access to this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only access to the HTTP-Layer. So only the Public IP.

Comment: In Mango we also have access to a socket API. But it doesn't help the OP I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, even with mango sockets, it's not possible to get the local ip address.

Comment: you can tell if it's wifi or 3G or CDMA or whatever connection, and the mobile operator. But it seems the most innocuous information, the local IP address is a no go.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution to this problem using UdpAnySourceMulticastClient. 
It finds your address within the local network. This works well when you are only behind 1 router. When there is more than one router you can start thinking to a more complex way to solve the networking problem.

Take a better look on Andy Pennell's blog:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2011/08/11/finding-your-own-ip-address-on-windows-phone-mango.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetHostNames()
```